# ASP.NET MVC Controllers and Extending the Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to catch a "controller not found" event from the framework?
Maybe this event doesn't exist. But if I just pick a URL to throw at the routing system of the framework like:

http://localhost:54321/foobar

The final result without modification is a 404 error.

Is the easiest way to catch this through a custom ControllerFactory? Then handle it from there.

**UPDATE:**
I'm looking for a way to catch and handle earlier in the request flow. Not at the controller level. See comments to Jon Galloway's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a catchall route at the end of your route declarations and handle it there.

```
/* all your other routes here */
routes.MapRoute("NotHandled", 
  "{*url}",
  new { controller = "NotFound", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: Is that "NotHandled" a magic string that is recognized by the framework?

Comment: No. That's just a name. The "magic" is that it's a catchall URL that hasn't been caught by anything else.

Comment: Right, you could name it "Monkey" if you wated. The {*yournamehere} route will match anything. That's why it's important to list it last, or it will prevent your other routes from matching.

Comment: Jon - then I would still have to have a hard-coded Controller. I'm looking for more control than that. Like the ability to kick up a Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine to handle the request. Thoughts?

Comment: Is a custom ControllerFactory then the best way to extend the MVC code without altering it?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are more issues here than meets the eye.

In particular, what happens when a user invokes a valid action on a valid controller, and the requested resource — product, article, sub-category etc — doesn’t exist?

Also, for search engine purposes, the invalid URL needs to return a true 404 error.

See the following post for a detailed examination of these issues:

**Strategies for resource-based 404 errors in ASP.NET MVC** 
http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Actually a controller not found would be handed to the "secondary system" if the secondary system could not handle it ... then you are right it should return a 404. A missing action on a controller - also 404